# Quick Start with Docker container http://{myIP}:81/ScadaLTS/ won't load

Tags: windows, docker, scadalts

Trying to follow the quickstart overt at https://github.com/SCADA-LTS/Scada-LTS.

I got the docker container downloaded and the initial command line issued:

```
docker run -it -e DOCKER_HOST_IP='myIP' -p 81:8080 scadalts/scadalts/root/start.sh
```

this command executes and finally ends with:

> INFO: Deployment of web application directory
>   /opt/scadalts/webapps/host-manager has finished in 88 ms Nov 25, 2018
>   11:17:39 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start INFO: Starting
>   ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"] Nov 25, 2018 11:17:39 PM
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start INFO: Starting
>   ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"] Nov 25, 2018 11:17:39 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start INFO: Server startup in
>   7812 ms

Which leads be to believe that the scadalts should now be running however when i browse over to http://myIP:81/ScadaLTS/ I am getting a 404 page.

The tomcat default page at http://myIP:81 seems to be loading.

How can i find out get more debugging information on understanding what ScadaLTS isn't loading ?

I am attempting to run this in a **Windows 10 docker container**.

Thank you in advance for any pointers / suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

The same happened here...

You're having a `404` error cause tomcat didn't load the project.

Tomcat needs a project in the `Tomcat/WebApps` folder to launch or a war file extract a project from.

So in your stats it may appears that your `WebApps` folder does not have project copied there or there is no folder project named `ScadaLTS` and that's why you couldn't reach http://{myIP}:81/ScadaLTS/.

So for a solution try `http://{ip}:81/ScadaBR` it's possible that by default you have a project name is `ScadaBR` in your [WebApps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uOsq5.png)<-(Check the picture)

or try another Scada image if not go for it from scratch it will make you understand a lot of things :3